# How to package EAR for GlassFish with Maven?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I want to package one EAR that will be deployed on GlassFish Server Open Source Edition. 
Here are the relevant parts of the `pom.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    ....
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <dependencies>
       ....
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I usually run `mvn compile` and `mvn package` in the command terminal. The resulting EAR has the following structure.

```
EAR/lib/*.jar
EAR/META-INF/application.xml
EAR/META-INF/META-INF.MF
EAR/META-INF/maven/...
```

The application.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>test-app</display-name>
  <library-directory>/lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

If I try to run `asadmin deploy test-app.ear` to deploy the EAR to GlassFish I get this error.

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 22; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/application.xml in archive ....
```

Here I rename `application.xml` to `glassfish-application.xml` and change its content to

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-application PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Java EE Application 6.0//EN"
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-application_6_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-application>
    <unique-id>67488732739338240</unique-id>
</glassfish-application>
```

If I rerun `asadmin deploy test-app.ear` GlassFish recognizes the deployment descriptor but throws the next error that says `Application [test-app] contains no valid components`.

Here I move all jars from `EAR/lib/*.jar` to `EAR/META-INF/lib/*.jar`.

If I now rerun `asadmin deploy test-app.ear` GlassFish recognizes the EAR as valid and deploys it.

Since I dont want to manually change the EAR every time. How can I configure Maven to 
1. Output a valid `application.xml` or `glassfish-application.xml`
2. Copy the dependencies not to `EAR/lib/` but to `EAR/META-INF/lib` (if it is really necessary)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I configure Maven to
>
> 1. Output a valid application.xml or glassfish-application.xml
> 2. Copy the dependencies not to EAR/lib/ but to EAR/META-INF/lib (if it is really necessary)

- **application.xml** can be autogenerated by maven-ejb-plugin and for the simple test I would leave it up to plugin
- for **dependencies copying** - it depends what you package in your ear (can be war/jar/...) but in general, it's a good idea, to let maven do it. For the purpose you miss in your pom.xml sections that would refer to modules (war/jar/...) you want to be included in there
- moreover I don't see a reason for non-standard libs folder you specified with: `<library-directory>`

So I'd go for config like the sample present [here](http://hordine.com/2012/09/how-to-create-a-maven-ear-project/).

To include the relevant sections in answer:

```
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myWar</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>myWarNameInTheEar.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/myWarConext</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myEjb</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>myEjbNameInTheEar.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </ejbModule>
                </modules>
                <displayName>My Ear Name displayed in the App Server</displayName>
                <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- Define the versions of your ear components here -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>myWar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>myEjb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please note you need to specify dependencies - for modules, but include those in modules section as well, to have them packaged.

Feel free to ask in case of any further questions.